# Tell maven to copy artifacts from directory other than maven-repo

Tags: maven

I am a quite new to using maven.
I am using maven as my build tool. When I build the code using maven, I copy the artifacts created during build, i.e. jars and zip to local maven-repo as well as one other back-up folder.
 I use maven to copy the artifacts from my maven-repo to the servers, where I have to deploy them. The pom that I use, automatically picks the latest artifacts and deploys them on the required server.
However, what I want to do is tell maven to pick the artifacts from a different folder at times rather than maven-repo.
I tried with  and  but to no avail.Please help:)

Comment: Also, please note I'm using maven-dependency-plugin

Comment: Is the "other directory" just a "plain directory" or can you assume it's another maven repo?

Comment: @dratewka no,the other directory cannot be assumed to be another maven-repo

Answer (score 3):

Technically speaking the answer is no, you can't tell maven to get artifacts from an arbitrary folder.  This is because the whole idea behind maven is that you can always reproduce your builds and you know exactly where all of your dependencies came from.

I would suggest you try maven-installing those other artifacts you have.  That would pull them into your repository and maven will work fine from there.  You could try to fool maven, but that kinda defeats the whole purpose of using maven.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best compromise between your way of doing things and Maven's is to rely on Maven's local repository, usually located in a `.m2/repository` directory under your home, as your backup folder. In this way the difference between doing a backup and doing a deploy would amount to just using `mvn install` in the first case and `mvn deploy` in the second.

With Maven you can do many things in a different way than the one intended by Maven's developers, but it's way easier to stick to Maven's conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Chris, that this is counter to what is expected usage of maven, but...
try this in your pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-internal-site1</id>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}\cometrepo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

change url to your local folder.

In the folder, the referenced artifacts should be in the same structure as they are referenced in the pom.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi All,thank you so much for all your responses:)...@sumit does the above mentioned change simply overrides my local maven-repository with the arbitrary directory?

Comment: it uses both, your settings repository first and then this pom repository to resolve artifacts not in your settings repository.

Comment: Hi @sumit...the <repositories> parameter has to be included in settings.xml under profiles or the pom.xml that I use for deployment..I could not figure out its usage in pom.xml that I'm using for deployment...A kind advice:)

Comment: In your pom.xml under project